# Creating REST API in GCP to read data from BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-cloud-functions, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-run

Very new in Google Cloud Platform & hence asking basic question.
I am looking for an API which will be hosted in GCP. An External application will call the API to read data from BigQuery.
Can anyone help me out with any example Code/Approach?

Looking for an End-to-End cloud based solution based on Python

Answer (score 1):

I can't provide you with a complete code example. But:

- You can setup your python API using (Flask for example)
- You can then use the python client to connect to BigQuery https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries
- Deploy your python API in Google App Engine, Cloud Run, Kubernetes, Compute, etc....

Do not forget to setup CORS and potential auth,
That's it

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `Python` program using the `Bigquery` [client](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python), then deploy this program as a `HTTP` [Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/create-deploy-http-python) or `Cloud Run` service :

```py
from flask import escape
from google.cloud import bigquery

import functions_framework

@functions_framework.http
def your_http_function(request):
    #HTTP Cloud Function.
  
    request_json = request.get_json(silent=True)
    request_args = request.args
    
    # example to retrieve argument param in the HTTP call
    if request_json and 'name' in request_json:
        name = request_json['name']
    elif request_args and 'name' in request_args:
        name = request_args['name']
    
   
    # Construct a BigQuery client object.
    client = bigquery.Client()

    query = """
      SELECT name, SUM(number) as total_people
      FROM `bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_2013`
      WHERE state = 'TX'
      GROUP BY name, state
      ORDER BY total_people DESC
      LIMIT 20
  """
  query_job = client.query(query)  # Make an API request.

  rows = query_job.result()  # Waits for query to finish

  for row in rows:
     print(row.name)

  return rows
```

You have to [deploy](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/create-deploy-http-python) your `Python` code as a Cloud Function in this example

Your function can be invoked with a `HTTP` call with a param `name` :

```
https://GCP_REGION-PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net/hello_http?name=NAME
```

You can also use `Cloud Run` that gives more flexibility because you deploy a `Docker` image.